# The listener info header is not added when using a batch listener

Tags: spring-kafka

The issue [2134](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2134) introduced a way to set arbitrary information using the info property of the *KafkaListener* annotation.
This info is then added as a header on the *ConsumerRecord*.

When using a batch listener, this header is not added on the records.

Based on the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#li-header), I'm not sure it's a bug but it would certainly make sense to also make it available in batch interceptors?

The internal headers are currently added in KafkaMessageListenerContainer#internalHeaders but this method is only called for single record listeners (see *KafkaMessageListenerContainer#checkEarlyIntercept*).

Any feedback on this would be welcome.

Comment: I don't see objections to have it over there as well, although we would need to iterate all the `ConsumerRecords` to add such a header before calling a `BatchInterceptor`. The doc states it clear that this `info` header is available only for `RecordInterceptor` and `RecordFilterStrategy`. Please, raise a GH issue and lets what Gary Russell thinks on the matter!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It seems we already iterate on the records in the KafkaMessageListenerContaine#invokeBatchListener. So, maybe we could invoke the interceptor once the list has been populated. GH issue has been created as suggested.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2249